# Table 4 Mimic Table 2

Tags: vba, input, row

When I add a row in table 2 I want a row to be automatically added to table 4 maintaining all formulas in each new row.  I've tried numerous VBA's and I cannot get it to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post some of the code you are trying. Review - [ask]

Comment: I gave up on it, so I don't have the code anymore.  It's really getting frustrated.  Basically I need table4 to be exactly like table2 without me having to do anything to table4 at all, I've tried everything and it's not working.